# Cannot return Firestore value in computed in VueJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component

I am trying to display a value stored in Firestore.

```
<p class="font-semibold">{{ user_displayName }}</p


export default {
   name: "the-navbar",
data() {
return {
name:''
}
},
computed:{
user_displayName() {

           const u = firebase.auth().currentUser;


           firebase
           .firestore()
           .collection('Colleges')
           .doc(u.uid)
           .onSnapshot(function(doc) {

             this.name=doc.data().displayName
             console.log(this.name)

            });
           console.log(this.name)

           return this.name
       },
}
```

No value or error is being returned and only first `console.log` is displaying the data (name).

Comment: that is different and does not solves the issue

Comment: Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. By the time your `return this.name` statement runs, your `this.name=doc.data().displayName` hasn't run yet. If you run the code in a debugger and set some breakpoint you can easily see this, and learn the flow of such asynchronous APIs.
The question Denis linked shows the same problem, as does an answer that I just wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887418/assigining-data-from-firestore-get-to-a-variable/57891552#57891552